# Strong topology on infinite dimensional Banach spaces not completely defined by linear continuous maps

Tags: functional-analysis

On Banach spaces you mostly look at two different topologies: the strong topology induced by the norm and the weak topology induced by the continuous linear functionals.
This also results in the statement that a linear operator between Banach spaces is strong continuous if and only if it is weak continuous.

But in the infinite-dimensional case the strong topology is strictly finer than the weak topology so obviously the linear maps between Banach spaces are not enough to define the strong topology (what I mean with this is, that the topology you get, when having all linear strong continuous maps being continuous, is the weak topology and not the strong topology).

So my question now is, why is that the case? Why are linear maps not enough? What is so restricting about linearity that you only get the weak topology? (in the infinite dimensional case as the topologies agree in the finite dimensional case)

As already noted the "problem" only occurs in the infinite dimensional case, so it most likely has something to do with that. My vague idea was that it may be because all vector spaces are isomorphic the direct sum of their ground field indexed by a basis and then maybe the weak topology is somehow this coproduct equipped with the "product topology", but the norm topology is the coproduct equipped with the "box topology". (With product and box topology on the coproduct I mean, that you can view the coproduct as a subspace of the product and then look a the subspace topology induced by those topologies)
I just thought this might be the right direction as the main "problem" as I see it  is that open sets in the weak topology are always unbounded (in the infinite dimensional case) because you can only "bound them in a finite number of directions", but with the box topology you could bound them in all direction as you can do with the norm.

But I have no idea if I am on the right track or how to prove it, as this construction heavily relies on choosing a basis and in the infinite dimensional case not all norms are equivalent and the box topology, in the finite dimensional case, seems somehow analogous to the maximum norm.

Comment: Weak open neighborhoods of zero contain the intersection of finitely many kernels of linear functionals - that's a subspace of finite co-dimension.  The open unit ball in the norm contains no non-zero subspace, so it can't contain a weak open neighborhood of zero.